# Use iscroll v5 with requirejs

Tags: backbone.js, requirejs, iscroll, iscroll4

I have a project with

1. [backbonejs](http://backbonejs.org/)
2. [requirejs](http://requirejs.org/)

and i want to include [iscroll v5](http://cubiq.org/iscroll-5-ready-for-beta-test)
but i don't know how i can load it and init it with requirejs...

I already tried to find a solution in any fork of the project but so far i didn't find anything.

I'm a newbie in JS so i need some help with this, anyone can post an example or provide a simple demo?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can include the path of the `iscroll plugin` in the configuration file where you declare the dependencies and paths for other files.

```
require.config({
    locale: 'en_us',

    baseUrl: 'baseUrl',
    paths: {
        // Paths of the libraries being used
        'Iscroll' : 'relative path to the file',
        ......
        ......  Other files
    },
    shim : { // If the library does not support AMD
        'Iscroll': {
             exports: 'Iscroll'
         },
    }
});
```

Now if you want to use that in a specfic Module, just include it

```
define(['Iscroll', other args], function(Iscroll, other args) {

});
```

Comment: thanks. but now how i can init a new Iscroll object and pass the div id? i always get an error because Iscroll can't access the id (is alway null)...

Comment: Do that in the render method after the element in the template is attached to the `DOM`